No username in terminal after creating user with no home directory
I create a new user on a Debian system with the following command:
root@mydebian:~# useradd -M -p mypass -u 1001 myuser
I deliberately don't want to create a home directory, so pass in the "-M" flag.
Now I try to change the user ID and make the shell a log in shell:
root@mydebian:~# su - myuser
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/myuser: No such file or directory
$ whoami
myuser

I have 2 questions:

I have a warning about cannot change to home directory - this makes sense because I didn't create one. However, why is it trying to navigate there by default?
Typically when I change user, the terminal would show something like myuser@mydebian:~$. Why in this case do I simply have $ in the terminal?


Presumably since you didn't specify a shell in your useradd command, you are getting the default shell from /etc/default/useradd (likely /bin/sh). See related How to setup a terminal prefix

-M only suppresses creation of homedir in case it doesn't exist yet, /home/myuser is still the default choice for the homedir. In other words: useradd created an entry in the database (/etc/passwd and such) with /home/myuser as the formal homedir, but because of -M it did not bother with creating the actual directory in the directory tree. See what man 8 useradd says about --home-dir. Side note: in Debian the manual states you should rather use adduser.

In addition to what @steeldriver said, $  is the default prompt in most shells (if you’re not root).   Anything else typically gets set in ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc or something similar, and you obviously don’t have any of those (since you don’t have ~).

Since the /home/myuser/ directory does not exist, of course /home/myuser/.profile and $HOME/.bashrc also do NOT exist.    So, your $PS1 is the default value (PS1=$). You can check the difference by typing env | grep PS1 using another normal account.

All these comments beg the question" Why do you not want to create a home directory for this user?"

@eyoung100 I have no files that need to be stored for this user. The user is created simply to manage a couple of docker containers. I have several such users, for different classes of docker container. I had no need for additional home directories, so my instinct was to not unnecessarily create them.

Instead off creating regular users, create users with ID's bellow 1,000.  This creates a system user.  Before doing so though Google "linux system users below 1,000" so as not to collide with a Package Manager created user.  Creating system users does not create a home directory or a login shell  See man useradd and look at the -r option, aka reserved or the alias for --system.  I believe -r will grab the next available ID under 1,000
